# I accidentally updated my git android project and lost my changes which is not committed. Is there any way to recover my changes?

Tags: android, git, visual-studio

After updating I am getting this notification.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem follow these steps to recover your local deleted file and code:

1. Go to toolbar: VCS->Git->UnStash Changes
2. From UnStash Changes pick recent Uncommitted changes
3. Click to view button
4. You will get a list of all files which get affected

Now you can merge manually those files which are affected and one thing you have to do manually add deleted files again.